# Opencv Video Capture .read function Different result on different PCs

Tags: python, opencv

I am having a code where I need to read a video file using opencv and get the frames out of that video. i am using Python for that and doing the following:

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
if not video.isOpened():
   self.logger.error("Error opening video from file {}".format(video_path))

ret, img = video.read()
while ret:
    frames.append(img)
    ret, img = video.read()

total_nbr_frames = len(frames)
```

I pass a video on one machine and I get a result of 35 frames. but when I use a different machine I get 7 frames.

Another video I tried was working on the first machine (27 frames) on the other the video was open but I couldn't read the frames (total = 0)

What could be the reason for that? is it hardware related? am I missing a library?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see this is totally hardware related. There's no library to help you increase the frame read speed.